# How to set an img src without knowing the file extension in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an empty img tag:

```
<img src="">
```

Then the src should be set with Javascript, but I just know the
name of the image, not the extension.

This won't work:

```
document.querySelector("img").src = "img/image1";
```

So I wonder if there is a way to set the src without specifying
the extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex should be able to find a match

Comment: How can you know the filename and not know the extension? The extension is part of the filename? Where is the part that you know coming from?

Comment: You would either need to handle this server side or you could try to load with different extensions (png, jpg, jpeg, gif, bmp, ...) and keep that one, which successfully loads.

Comment: first one here that got it: Barmar     We dont' know.   so @Boel please tell where you know your img name from.    Micah Henning's answer is a right one, but still not answering a main problem.. is it? dunno..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a scripting language running on the server, you can run a script there that searches the image directory for the name with any extension. You set the `src` URL to point to the script, and the server can search for the file and send a redirect.

```
document.querySelector("img").src = "find_image.php?name=image1";
```

`find_image.php` would be something like:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/" . $name . ".*");
if (!empty($files)) {
    header("Location: /img/" . basename($files[0]));
} else {
    // Redirect to a default image if the file can't be found
    header("Location: /img/default.gif");
}
```

Here's a kludgey way to do it on the client, if you know that the extension is one of a limited set. It uses the `onerror` attribute of the image to try a different extension if the previous one failed.

```
function tryImages(img, name) {
    img.src = "img/" + name ".jpg";
    img.onerror = function() {
        img.src = "img/" + name ".png";
        img.onerror = function() {
            img.src = "img/" + name ".gif";
        };
    };
tryImages(document.querySelector("img"), "image1");
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I'm making a mobile app. I have the images in the "img" folder. For instance, inside img folder: image1.jpg, image2.png, image3.gif. But I only know the name of the file, like image1, image2, etc. I wonder if there is a way to set the img src only knowing the name, always client side.

Comment: You can try one extension, and use an `onerror` handler to try a different extension if that fails.

Comment: it can be done with AJAX --- client / server / client-side    I---I best answer @Barmar

Comment: True, it could be done with AJAX and ArrayBuffers.  Magic numbers could be used to validate that it's an image and of which type.  But its random attempts at guessing an extension pose a huge security risk, wasted bandwidth, and wasted processing time.  What a strange constraint!

Comment: @Boel I've updated the answer to show how to do it with `onerror`.

Comment: I'd recommend using recursion for the tryImages method, perhaps with something like `['.png','.jpg','.gif'].forEach(function (ext) { /* ... */ });`

Comment: Can't do it with `forEach` because, `onerror` is asynchronous. If there were more than 2 or 3 extensions, I would generalize it, but I didn't feel like writing the more complex code for that.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever your `src` attribute says is what the browser will request from the server.  If you configure your server to use default extensions somehow, then it could be possible.  But it's always better to be explicit about what you're requesting.

In any case, if you want to dynamically add an image to the page, don't put in bad markup.  Create the element on the fly.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.alt = 'This is a river.'; // alt is required per HTML spec
image.src = 'your/image/location';
document.body.appendChild(image); // or wherever you want it
```

Comment: How does this help with the problem that he doesn't know the extension to put in `image.src`?

Comment: Unless there are oracles or gods on StackExchange, nobody can tell the questioner what extension to use.  An extension is just part of the filename; there's nothing inherently special about it.  And how can we know his or her filenames?!

Comment: He wants a solution that searches the directory for the filename with any of the image extensions.

Comment: But in any case, @Barmar, I mentioned configuring the web server to use default extensions, similar to how Apache would default to index.html, for example, if a user navigated to a directory instead of directly to the file they intended.

Answer (score 0):

/img/image1.*/

Regular expressions are what you need

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

But on the backend(what language are you using? PHP, Javascript, ruby?)...not front end javascript.

Comment: The webserver won't expand a regular expression when the browser asks for a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for all the file types and see for the `onerror` event. Like this :

```
var image = document.createElement("IMG");
image.src = "myfile.jpg";
document.appendChild(image);

for(var i = 0; i<2; i++){
 image.onerror = function(){
  if(image.src == "myfile.jpg"){
   image.src = "myfile.png";
  }else if(image.src == "myfile.png"){
   image.src = "myfile.gif";
  }
}
```